# Trouble with Loop for diagonal object

Tags: java, loops, object, int, diagonal

ok so I am having trouble having my y4 be recognized. Everytime i build, the file it keeps on saying cannot find symbol in every thing that has y4. Such as this.

```
y4= 50;
        for(int x=625; x<875; x+=25)
        {
            cloud.moveCloud(g,x,y4);
            Expo.delay(100);
            cloud.eraseCloud(g);
            intro.drawBackground(g);
            intro.IntroWords(g);
            intro.drawSun(g);
            intro.drawTrees(g);
            y4-=3;
        }
        cloud.moveCloud(g,875,y4);
```

i already int y over in this code.

```
    Hare2 hare2 = new Hare2();
    hare2.drawHare2(g);
        for(int x=500; x < 750; x+=25)
        {
            hare2.moveHare2(g,x,325);
            Expo.delay(100);
            hare2.eraseHare2(g);
        }
        hare2.moveHare2(g,750,325);
        int y = 325;
        for(int x=750; x < 900; x+=25)
        {
            hare2.moveHare2(g,x,y);
            Expo.delay(100);
            hare2.eraseHare2(g);
            y-=20;
        }
        hare2.moveHare2(g,900,y);
```

please help me :(

Comment: Where do you first declare y4? That place needs to have its type. Something like `int y4 = 50;`

Comment: nvm, i got it. I didnt know you had to declare it. Thank you so much.